# How to check if permissions are allocated by the user using compile sdk 22?

Tags: android, permissions

**Note:** I know how the permission model works in `Marshmallow`. Please don't give answers regarding that.

My application uses `compileSdk` 22. I want to write a utility to detect what permissions are allocated by the user. If the user has a `Marshmallow` device, then he can disable the permissions at any time. I tried the following piece of code

```
if((packageManager.checkPermission(permissionName,context.getPackageName())== PackageManager
      .PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
    // permission is granted
  }else{
    // permission is not granted.
  }
```

This code returns true for every permission declared in the `Manifest.xml` file. If I run this code on an `Marshmallow` device, and then disable some of the permissions manually, then also this code returns true for the disabled permissions.

So if there any method before `compileSdk` 23, which can tell what permissions the user has granted to the application.

**P.S.**: The method need not be a direct api. Some kind of hack is also allowed.

Comment: I think you will need to raise your `compileSdkVersion` to `23` or higher for any solution here. [`PermissionChecker` sounds like what you want](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/PermissionChecker.html), or you can use [the device admin APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getPermissionGrantState%28android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with user permission.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example in my SplashActivity.

### SplashActivity

```
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    }, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                }else {
                    startMain();
                }
            }else{
                startMain();
            }
```

Later you check if user accept it or not.

### RequestResult

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                startMain();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PERMISSIONS !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```